# How to import and use JsInterop with LibGDX (Gradle)?

Tags: gradle, gwt, libgdx, gwt-jsinterop

I cannot figure out how to import and use [JsInterop](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJsInterop.html) in a LibGDX project.

My GWT version in html `build.gradle` is correct:

```
gwt {
    gwtVersion='2.8.0'
...
```

In project's `build.gradle` :

```
project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
 ...

    dependencies {
       ...
        compile "com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:1.0.1"
    }
}
```

Still I cannot compile, I get errors:

```
error: package jsinterop.annotations does not exist
error: cannot find symbol class JsType
```

I have read about the `generateJsInteropExports` flag, I tried to put it in different places (maybe wrong ones?), did not work either.

Am I missing something?

Comment: My guess is that you need to put that under all dependencies or put that in your core module. By putting that in html dependencies you cannot use anything from JsInterop in places other than your html module.

Comment: @retodaredevil Alright, now I can compile. However, now it always says that 'com' is not defined.

Comment: can you post more of your build.gradle?

Comment: I managed to get it work! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836324/jsinterop-com-is-not-defined